# Why is accessing CustomStringConvertible’s description discouraged?

Tags: swift, string, option-type, customstringconvertible

[Apple’s docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customstringconvertible) for `CustomStringConvertible` say:

> Accessing a type’s `description` property directly […] is discouraged.

Why?

---

Below is an example where using `description` seems useful to me. How would I get the same results otherwise?

```
func dontPrintNil(_ s: String?) {
   if s == nil {
        print("placeholder")
    } else {
        print(s!)
    }
}

let s: String? = nil

dontPrintNil(s)                          // → placeholder
dontPrintNil(s?.description)             // → placeholder
dontPrintNil(String(describing: s))      // → nil
dontPrintNil("\(s)")                     // → nil
```

Comment: I read the following on [SwiftDoc.org](http://swiftdoc.org/v3indexing/protocol/CustomStringConvertible/):
“`String(instance)` will work for an `instance` of any type, returning its `description` if the `instance` happens to be `CustomStringConvertible`. Using `CustomStringConvertible` as a generic constraint, or accessing a conforming type's `description` directly, is **therefore** discouraged.” (Emphasis mine.)

I can’t see how the first sentence implies the second one. Do the docs assume that we always want the conversion to String to be successful?

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, [a previous version](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7f31d4e8890e227a8c291d28d7646784dd26ebc6/stdlib/public/core/OutputStream.swift#L47) of that same piece of documentation reads:

> Note: `String(instance)` will work for an `instance` of *any* type, returning its `description` if the `instance` happens to be `CustomStringConvertible`.  Using `CustomStringConvertible` as a generic constraint, or accessing a conforming type's `description` directly, is therefore discouraged.

To me, this suggests that what they're worried about, is people needlessly going out of their way to *cast values* to `CustomStringConvertible`, instead of using the more convenient `String(describing:)`.
If you don't know about that initializer, casting (or using generic constraints) would indeed be the natural thing to reach for.

Now—why did they eventually remove the “therefore” logical link from the comment? Maybe it's just a side-effect of the rewrite, or maybe they feel it's not that simple, which would mean we still don't have our answer.